# Excel calculates the columns when creating a new row

Tags: vba, excel

Even if I set calculations to manual, excel automatically calculates the columns each time a new row is created. I've created a simple sheet to demonstrate the problem:

The source data (srcSheet) contains 1000 rows:

[image]

Which are copied to two "destination sheets":

[image]

The first has a couple of "Slow columns" which contain very heavy formulas.

The copying operation takes 12.5s on my machine for this sheet.

The second "destination sheet" does not contain these slow columns:

[image]

The copying operation takes 0.0039s.

Is there any way to copy the data without calculating each row?

Here's the spreadsheet I was using: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ue9n4a8avstpzf/Excel%20Calculation%20Demo.xlsm

Here's the code I'm using to copy the data:

```
Dim sourceRange As Range, destRange As Range

Sub Test()
Dim StartTime As Double, EndTime As Double
StartTime = Timer

Sheets("SrcSheet").Select
Set sourceRange = Range("srcTb[Data]")
Sheets("DestSheet1").Select
Set destRange = Range("destTb[Data]")

sourceRange.Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=destRange

EndTime = Timer
Debug.Print "PerfTest1: ", EndTime - StartTime

StartTime = Timer
Sheets("DestSheet2").Select
Set destRange = Range("destTb2[Data]")

sourceRange.Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=destRange
EndTime = Timer
Debug.Print "PerfTest2: ", EndTime - StartTime
End Sub
```

Update re: Sathish,

I've got the following timings after trying your suggestions:

```
Testing semi-automatic: 0
PerfTest1:     7.38671875 
PerfTest2:     0.0390625 
Testing manual: 0
PerfTest1:     18.24609375 
PerfTest2:     19.48828125 
Testing semi-automatic: 1
PerfTest1:     7.234375 
PerfTest2:     20.97265625 
Testing manual: 1
PerfTest1:     18.859375 
PerfTest2:     19.546875 
Testing semi-automatic: 2
PerfTest1:     7.26171875 
PerfTest2:     20.796875 
Testing manual: 2
PerfTest1:     18.03515625 
PerfTest2:     19.640625 
Testing semi-automatic: 3
PerfTest1:     7.234375 
PerfTest2:     20.55078125 
Testing manual: 3
PerfTest1:     18.296875 
PerfTest2:     19.46484375
```

On average it seems that semi-automatic is faster but the numbers are a bit confusing...

```
Sub Clear()
    Sheets("DestSheet2").Select
    Range("A3").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Rows.Delete

    Sheets("DestSheet1").Select
    Range("A3").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
     Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Rows.Delete
End Sub

Sub TestManual()
Clear
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 Test
End Sub

Sub TestSemiAutomatic()
Clear
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationSemiautomatic
 Test
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to

*Automatic Except Tables* > *Tools* > *Options* >*Calculation*

VBA - also try this in code

`Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False`